# Rouché Theorem to calculate the number of zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I calculate the number of zeros of $\cos z+3z^3$ using the Rouché Theorem?

Comment: Within which domain?

Comment: In the circle of radius 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z) = 3z^3$ and $g(z) = \cos z$. Then on $|z|=1$, we have $|f(z)| = 3$ and
$$
|g(z)| = \left| \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2} \right| \le \frac12 ( |e^{iz}| + |e^{-iz}| ) \le e < 3.
$$

Rouché implies that $f+g$ and $f$ have the same number of zeros inside the unit circle, i.e. $3$. (The estimate on $|\cos z|$ is very rough, but enough for this purpose.)

Comment: I believe you need to show something like $|f(z)+g(z)| < |f(z)|$ to apply Rouché?

Comment: @copper.hat You can formulate Rouché's theorem in several different ways. One common formulation (even Wikipedia's chosen one) is: if $|g| < |f|$ on $\partial\Omega$, then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros on $\Omega$.

Comment: I need more caffeine. I am showing $f$ and $g$ have the same zero count, your version shows $f$ and $f+g$ have the same zero count.

Comment: $f$ has 3 zeros in $\mathbb{C}$, but how do you know that all 3 zeros are inside $|z| \leq 1$?

Comment: @ASlowLearner Surely you can solve $3z^3=0$ explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Try $g(z) = \cos z +3 z^3$, $f(x) = -3 z^3$. Then $|g(z)+f(z)| = |\cos z|$. If $|z| = 1$, then $|\cos z| = \cosh (\operatorname{Im} z) \le e < 3$. Since $|f(z)| = 3$ when $|z|=1$, we have $|g(z)+f(z)| < |f(z)|$ for $z$ on the unit circle. Both $f,g$ are entire, hence $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros (counted by multiplicity) inside the unit circle. Hence the answer is three.

Comment: $f$ has three zeros inside the circle.